# Is There a Syntax to Remove the First Parameter from a map() Arrow Function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Is there a way to keep the first parameter `n` in the `map()` as a void? I am creating CSS shapes, so I only need the second one.

**Thanks!**

```js
const Star = () => {
  return (
   <div id='Star'>
     {[...Array(3)].map((n, i) => <span style={{transform: `rotate(${i * 50}deg)`}}/>)}
    </div>
  )
}   

ReactDOM.render(
  <Star/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
#Star {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
#Star span {
    background: green;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: just discard the variable - dont use it

Comment: Is the code not working in some way?  What's the actual problem to be solved?

Comment: also seems a bit silly to do this with `.map` when a normal loop would do.

Comment: You can usually use a underscore on the first variable, but its a convention, there is no answer for this

Comment: I think there was an attempt to allow `(, i)` but it didn't get implented. Most projects/companies simply use _ for the unused param.
@DanielA.White it's a react component so he does need the `.map`.

Comment: @DanielA.White This is a perfectly valid use of map since he wants to return the array of spans. Using a for loop he would have to emulate map() and push the spans into a temporary array. Using map() avoids the need to create a temporary array

Comment: @slebetman but there are 2 additional temporary arrays - the one that is made with `Array(3)` and spread into the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no really clean way to do it afaik. There are few options I can think of:

1. Declaring unused arg as `_`. In this case the `_` variable will still be initialised, so the benefits are only visual.

```
[...Array(3)].map((_, i) => <span style={{transform: `rotate(${i * 50}deg)`}}/>)
```

2. Using rest params

```
[...Array(3)].map((...params) => <span style={{transform: `rotate(${params[1] * 50}deg)`}}/>)
```

Could be also written inline, which might be a bit confusing.

```
[...Array(3)].map((...[,i]) => <span style={{transform: `rotate(${i * 50}deg)`}}/>)
```